# Key binding not responding in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to bind the `<Return>` key event on two `Entry` but the validation code isn't working (there's no displayed error, the `validate` function just doesn't apply)

Here's the entry initialization :

```py
from tkinter import *

fi = Tk()
l_n = Entry(fi)
l_t = Entry(fi)
b1 = Button(fi, cursor="hand2", overrelief=GROOVE, text="Run", command=someUnrelatedFunction, state=DISABLED)
```

And here's the code that is suppopsed to bind the validation function to the entries :

```py
l_n.bind("<Return>",lambda name='l_n':validate(name))
l_t.bind("<Return>",lambda name='l_t':validate(name))
```

Finally, here's the packing and the validation function :

```py
l_n.pack()
l_t.pack()

def validate(name):
    global v1,v2,n,t
    if name=='l_n':
        v1=True
        s=l_n.get()
        n=int(s)
        l_n.delete(0,END)
    elif name=='l_t':
        v2=True
        s=l_t.get()
        t=float(s)
        l_t.delete(0,END)
    if v1==True and v2==True:
        b1.config(state=NORMAL)
```

What's the problem here ?

Comment: What's not working the way you want?  Your code binds the `<Return>` event to both Entry widgets.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it crash? Does it return the wrong results?

Comment: I edited with what doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tkinter, when you do the binding, tkinter itself adds another argument to the callback that holds information of the event. So when you are are trying to pass parameters with lambda, you should consider that as well.

```
l_n.bind("<Return>", lambda event, name='l_n': validate(name))
l_t.bind("<Return>", lambda event, name='l_t': validate(name))
```